# Why single task is getting triggered during read from SQL-Server using SPARK

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, databricks, azure-databricks

I am trying to read a dataset from sqlserver using pyspark. I mentioned below parameters to create multiple number of partition to achieve parallelization. I can see n number of partition created but only single single task is getting executed to retrieve the result. SQL server read is not happening parallelly .Not sure where exactly I am doing wrong . I can see predicate has been created based on upper and lower bound .

I tried using below option :

```
.option("lowerBound", '<value>') \
.option("upperBound", '<value>') \
.option("partitionColumn", "<column name>") \
.option("numPartitions", <value>) \
.option("fetchsize", <value>).load()
```

My cluster is :
2-3 Workers:32-48 GB Memory 8-12 Cores
1 Driver:16 GB Memory, 4 Cores
Runtime:10.4.x-scala2.12

[Date and Timestamps columns are supported as partition column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P5QR2.png)

Answer (score 0):

In order to parallelize this operation, the column you are using for splitting must be of integer datatype ,so that spark can have a definite range of values to provide as a key to each of the workers.

Comment: Spark 3.0+ supports date and timestamp as well.

Comment: Try to check if the timestamp and date format are jvm compatible